# How to inject HTML banner code using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have the following block of HTML code which I don't want to alter on a static HTML page:

```
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo01.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo02.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo03.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo04.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo05.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo06.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo07.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo08.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo09.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo10.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo11.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo12.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo13.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo14.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg"></div>
```

Without the use of JQuery, I need to have this implemented using Vanilla Javascript to dynamically inject banner code after every 5, 15, 30 occurrence of `<div class="wrapper"></div>`

The increament is starting at 10, and after each occurrence, the next number is previous number plus its increment plus 5.

eg. 5, 15, 30, 50, 75, 105, etc.

Another challenge for me is that I also couldn't figure out how to get the mathematic formula to translate to coding.

A sample banner code to be injected:

```
<div id="banner5"><ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>

<div id="banner15"><ins data-revive-zoneid="456" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>

<div id="banner30"><ins data-revive-zoneid="456" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>
```

The resulting outcome would be:

```
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo01.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo02.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo03.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo04.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo05.jpg"></div>
<div id="banner5"><ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo06.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo07.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo08.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo09.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo10.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo11.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo12.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo13.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo14.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg"></div>
<div id="banner15"><ins data-revive-zoneid="456" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>
    :
    :
    :
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo30.jpg"></div>
<div id="banner30"><ins data-revive-zoneid="789" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: "Without the use of JQuery"

Comment: The project requiring me not using JQuery

Comment: Select all banners, iterate them, add a condition to insert the banners when needed. Have you tried? Check [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: I have the idea, logic, and math drafted out, but not sure how to make the actual javascript implementation using QuerySelector to the above scenario.

Comment: KDX : Try it using what Jordi pointed out and show us where you think you are missing something. It is not pretty hard.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use **`[].forEach`** to iterate all `.wrapper` elements
- Use `parentNode.insertBefore` to insert Element at specific position

```js
var start = 5,
            multiple = 5;
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
    [].forEach.call(elements, function (elem, index) {
        var elemt = '<span>' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = elemt;
        elem.appendChild(div.firstChild);
    });
    var counter = 1;
    [].forEach.call(elements, function (elem, index) {
        var localIndex = index + 1;
        if (localIndex == start) {

            var toAppendHTML = '<div id="banner' + start + '"><ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins>'+start+'\
                    <script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"><\/script>\
</div>';
            var divElement = document.createElement('div');
            divElement.innerHTML = toAppendHTML;
            insertAfter(divElement.firstChild, elements[index]);
            start += multiple * ++counter;
        }
    });

    function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo01.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo02.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo03.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo04.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo05.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo06.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo07.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo08.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo09.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo10.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo11.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo12.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo13.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo14.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works as desired, except I need to modify `var element = document.getElementById('banner' + start);` to create my own `banner div` element using `var element = document.createElement('div'); element.id  = 'banner'+start;`.  However, another issue arises I couldn't figure out.  Using `element.innerHTML = '<ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins>1';` works.  But once I have `<script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script>` after `</ins>`, I'm getting console error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.  Can't Javascript be used?

Comment: @KDX — You were so close, you had to escape closing tag character(`<\/script>`). Check the edit..

Comment: Everything works well so far.  Is it possible to tweak it to set a limit so that at most (no more than) 5 `<div id="bannerX">` are created?

Comment: @KDX – _Limit_ `===` `If-Condition`

Comment: I get the logic, but can you show me a quick example?  I'm currently using `if (localIndex == start && start <= 75)`.  I think it's not that elegant and less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this ;)

```
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo01.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo02.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo03.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo04.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo05.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo06.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo07.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo08.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo09.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo10.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo11.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo12.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo13.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo14.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo01.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo02.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo03.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo04.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo05.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo06.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo07.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo08.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo09.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo10.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo11.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo12.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo13.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo14.jpg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"><img class="lazyload" src="/img/foo15.jpg"></div>


<script>
  var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
  for(var i in wrappers)
  {
    if(i > 9)
    {
      if(i%5 == 0)
      {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id  = 'banner'+i;
        div.innerHTML = '<ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins>';
        wrappers[i].parentElement.insertBefore(div, wrappers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started:

You can use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select elements by class:

```
var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
```

You can use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to inject HTML to the DOM after an element:

```
someWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterend',
    '<div id="banner5"><ins data-revive-zoneid="123" data-revive-id="f123123fd4f12d4f123d12"></ins><script async src="//adserver.com/asyncjs.php"></script></div>'
);
```