# Is there a vanilla JavaScript technique for dynamically inserting common code into HTML pages, similar to PHP's include capability?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a multi-page HTML site with common code that is reused on each page (for example, navbar code, Analytics, stylesheet imports, etc).

Is there a way to dynamically insert that common code in a manner that achieves the same result as PHP's include capability, and makes the code easier to maintain?

I've seen similar questions but not all seem to speak to what I want to achieve with the site I am working with. For example:

- [How to inject HTML banner code using Vanilla Javascript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760343/how-to-inject-html-banner-code-using-vanilla-javascript)

*Important: Much of the code I want to insert/import will be `<header>` code that is necessary to properly render the pages so it will need to be inserted as the page loads.*

Any suggestions? **Please limit suggestions to vanilla JavaScript**. I don't know JQuery at this point and want to try do this with JS.

Comment: Why javascript specifically ? you added the php tag to the question, would you like to discuss server-side solutions (other than php perhaps) as well ?

Comment: From what/where will you be serving the website? Can't you use PHP or any server-side code?

Comment: I'm using a [very ad hoc PHP model](http://modiinbus.com) at the moment and I think it may be blocking me from doing things like highlighting nav buttons for current pages because my PHP implementation is pretty rough (just guessing). I'm learning JS at the moment and thought it may be useful.

Comment: @Salketer I know even less PHP than JS (it's on my list after JS) so that may be a simpler solution in the medium term. The site runs mostly fine on PHP for now, I'm exploring alternatives.

Comment: What you'd like to do will be way easier in PHP than javascript, trust me.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to do what you want, but I think a template engine such as EJS or similar will meet your needs.

Do keep in mind though the implications of doing this client-side.  Crawlers and such that don't run JavaScript won't have the benefit of seeing what's supposed to be on your page.

What you should probably be doing instead is running these JavaScript templates server-side, outputting static pages which then can be put on your web server or CDN.

Comment: Thanks. Newbie question: how do you run JS templates server-side, generally speaking? Is this where Node.js comes in?

Comment: @PaulJacobson Yes.  You can either run Node.js as a server with a framework like Express which has some quick connectors to template engines, or write a quick script to run the templates on a directory of files or something to output static HTML.  I'm suggesting the latter, as it seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack? You could use a packaging system to fuse all your JS into one file, same for CSS. That way you have only only script and one link to add to each page. But for HTML parts, they would be added with javascript ajax and that shouldn't be a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have multiple pages at all? Cant you just have one page, then update a certain ( the main part) part of your page with new code content instead of a redirect. ( if you want to see this in action visit http://google.com, http://twitter.com and many many more ). the *index.html* would then look like this:

```
<body>
 <div id = "nav" >
  <a href = "/whatever.html" class = "redirect" > Whatever </a>
 </div>
 <div id = "main" >
  Some content
 </div>
<script>
  //embed jquery
 $(_ => {
  $(".redirect").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main").load(this.href);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. How would I do that with vanilla JS? What would the directory structure be for a site built like that?

Comment: @paul well, use `getElementsByClassName`, `XMLHttpRequest` and many others, or just embed jquery ( its used by nearly every page, so it will not really increase the pages loading time as most browsers have it allready in cache) :/

Comment: I ran the script in a test page and it certainly takes me closer to an alternative but I noticed it replaces the original page completely. How would I set this up so that it only loads the external page *within* the host `index.html` page?